# select angular doesn't show value correctly

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array with arrays, which simulate a csv book:

```
[
  [ 'PROBANDO', 'SUBIENDO DESDE CSV', '1', '900', '', '2', '1' ],
  [ 'PROBANDO', 'SUBIENDO DESDE CSV', '1', '900', '850', '3', '1' ],
  [ 'PROBANDO', 'SUBIENDO DESDE CSV', '1', '900', '850', '2', '1' ]
]
```

and what I want is to select a category (index 6) and change it in the array.

this code changes the category perfectly, but I have to select a second time for that category I selected to remain selected.

**ts**

```
  selectCat(event, idx: any) {
    let prod: any[] = this.productos[idx];

    prod.splice(6, 1, event.target.value); // 6 = posicion de la columna categoria

    this.productos.splice(idx, 1, prod);
  }
```

**html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of productos; index as idx">
    <td *ngFor="let i of p; index as ind">

        <p *ngIf="ind <= 4"> {{ i }} </p>

        <select *ngIf="ind == 6" name="cat" (change)="selectCat($event, idx)"
            class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option *ngFor="let c of categorias" [value]="c.id"> {{ c.categoria }}
            </option>
        </select>

    </td>
</tr>
```

categorias array:

```
[
  {id: 2, categoria: "Cat22"},
  {id: 3, categoria: "cat3"},
  {id: 1, categoria: "Ropa"}
]
```

**-----------------------------------------------------------**

I put the value selected above the select to verify is correct
[image: I put the value selected above the select to verify is correct]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide your categorias array?

Comment: @SurajGupta added

Comment: i have created demo for the same, pls have a look [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rmojwp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @SurajGupta yes, the problem was that the ngModel was missing! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try using `[(ngModel)]="p[ind]"` instead of `(change)="selectCat($event, idx)"`. i think the data is not correctly bound to the select input. if i understand it correctly, the dropdowns should also show "Ropa" on initial load.